# Changing code after generating apk file in android studio

Tags: java, android, apk

Can I make changes to my code after I have generates the apk for release ? Because I had to build apk but now have to do some changes. Can somebody tell ?

Comment: Only if you know how to edit bytecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make changes to the code and build as many apks as you want.

if you are using android studio,
After changing your code, just go to build>generate_signed_apk to build an signed apk for release.

Comment: So the point is that i can change the code sing a new apk, but i cannot test imediately on emulator or real device. @Sid

Comment: if you are creating an apk for testing then you dont have to sign it with your key you can debug the apk by build>run with your emulator or device(with usb debugging enabled) attached.

Comment: I have signed it unfortunately for releasing because i had to the project. And I was thinking if I could do any chane now.. but it seems it cannot be done @Sid

Comment: Well, if i understood you correctly, then you r trying to make changes to the apk file. The code in a apk file in stored in bytecode, which is harder to read and change, and even if you changed it, your certificates(digest) will be invalid then. Easier and not good way> Use any decompiler like jadx to decompile the code make changes and rebuild it and resign it.

Comment: I understand now. Seems difficult. Thank youu @Sid